# How can loop through perl constant

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, constants

I want to do the same as below

```
my @nucleotides = ('A', 'C', 'G', 'T');
foreach (@nucleotides) {
    print $_;
}
```

but using

```
use constant NUCLEOTIDES => ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'];
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: 'use constant' is more trouble than it's worth here. Why not just 'our @NUCLEOTIDES = qw(A C G T);' ??

Comment: Because the information in this constant is not going to be modified through out the run-time even though it's not really that 'constant' here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
use constant NUCLEOTIDES => [ qw{ A C G T } ];

foreach (@{+NUCLEOTIDES}) {
    print;
}
```

Though beware: Although NUCLEOTIDES is a constant, the elements of the referenced array (e.g. `NUCLEOTIDES->[0]`) can still be modified.

Answer (score 8):

Why not make your constant return a list?

```
sub NUCLEOTIDES () {qw(A C G T)}

print for NUCLEOTIDES;
```

or even a list in list context and an array ref in scalar context:

```
sub NUCLEOTIDES () {wantarray ? qw(A C G T) : [qw(A C G T)]}

print for NUCLEOTIDES;

print NUCLEOTIDES->[2];
```

if you also need to frequently access individual elements.

Comment: You first function is equivalent to `use constant NUCLEOTIDES => qw/A C G T/`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the constant pragma, then you can just say

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant NUCLEOTIDES => qw/A C G T/;

for my $nucleotide (NUCLEOTIDES) {
   print "$nucleotide\n";
}
```

The item on the right of the fat comma (`=>`) does not have to be a scalar value.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $nucleotides = NUCLEOTIDES;

foreach ( @$nucleotides ) { 
}
```

Or you could make this utility function:

sub in (@) { 
       return @_ == 1 && ref( $*[0] ) eq 'ARRAY' ? @{ shift() } 
            :                                      @*
            ; 
   }

And then call it like this:

```
for my $n ( in NUCLEOTIDES ) { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is for completeness, while https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972542/6607497 is more elegant)

After having tried things like `@{NUCLEOTIDES}` and `@{(NUCLEOTIDES)}` unsuccessfully, I came up with introducing an unused `my` variable:

```
foreach (@{my $r = NUCLEOTIDES}) {
}
```